# how to fix Persisted Navigation Term Set Synchronization?

Tags: sharepoint-server

When I open my Event viewer they show the `critical error event ID 2158`
and the task category for the error is "`Unified Logging Service`".

I checked failed Timer Jobs failed that shows the `Persisted Navigation Term Set Synchronization`.

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can troubleshoot the issue as below:

1. Click the  Persisted Navigation Term Set Synchronization timer job, disable it and re-enable, then click Run now, check if the issue exists.
2. Check if the Managed metadata service application started and worked correctly.

Here is a similar [post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b827162b-1c23-4f37-aba7-93f8746b8ee0/persisted-navigation-term-set-synchronization-failure?forum=sharepointadmin).

If the issue exists, [clear the SharePoint configure cache](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2010-2013-21f55320).